# How to connect cakephp 4.x to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

How can I connect cakephp version 4.x to mongoDB. I tried many ways but couldn't. I need help from the community. Thanks

Comment: It can help you 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow below steps

1. Install the library by running:

   ```
   composer require mongodb/mongodb
   ```
2. You can create a folder in your src folder

   Example you location is : `app/cake/src/Mongo/connection.php`
3. Then you can write below code to connect mongo

   ```
   <?php 

   namespace App\Mongo;
   use MongoDB\Client as Mongo;

   class Mongo {

   public function connection(){
      $user = "admin";
      $pwd = 'password';

      return new Mongo("mongodb://${user}:${pwd}@127.0.0.1:27017");

   '''
   }
   ```
4. Use this class in any controller

```
    <?php 
        use App\Mongo\Mongo;
        //In before filter method 
        $this->mongo = new Mongo;
        '''''
```